# Asp net core Signalr with Subdomains

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

i want to setup a tenant based system that also includes signalr for that reason i need signalr to work with subdomains.
I have hosted signalr with my normal controllers in the same asp net core 6 application.
So for example I have Customer A that accesses the signalr Application through http://a.domain.com/ProcessHub and Customer B that should be able to use http://b.domain.com/ProcessHub

But in my local test application http://localhost:port/ProcessHub works but http://a.localhost:port/ProcessHub doesnt. If i try to connect to it in my Testclient i get

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The Host is unknown
```

If i try to send a request from something like postman i get 404 with Connection ID required

How can i enable Signalr to also work with subdomains

EDIT:

Its a problem i only have on localhost if i change hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 a.domain.com
127.0.0.1 b.domain.com
```

everything works find and this will also be the case when we deploy it on kubernetes we just need the subdomains for networking reasons

Comment: Did you mean that you have an application which is designed for multiple tenants, and tenant A visit `A.localhost:44312` while tenant B visit `B.localhost:44312`. By the time you used signalR to realize the pushing notification feature and also need to push message to A or B tenant separately?